# Updating and editing lists in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop, if-statement

I have a data table that looks like this:
[image]

I want to update each list and to show the lineup at the time of the substitution and remove/add a player if they come in/out of the game.  I would like to save each edit in the vlineup/hlineup column and then remove/add based on the value in the cell from the above row.  My thought process was this:

```
for i in range (1, len(subs)):

    subs['vlineup'].iloc[i] = subs['vlineup'].iloc[i-1]
    subs['hlineup'].iloc[i] = subs['hlineup'].iloc[i-1]

    if subs['team'].iloc[i] == home:      
        subs['vlineup'].iloc[i] = subs['vlineup'].iloc[i-1]
        if subs['type'].iloc[i] == 'OUT':
            subs['hlineup'].iloc[i].remove(subs['checkname'].iloc[i])           
        elif subs['type'].iloc[i] == 'IN':
            subs['hlineup'].iloc[i].append(subs['checkname'].iloc[i])
            

    elif subs['team'].iloc[i] == visitor:
        subs['vlineup'].iloc[i] = subs['vlineup'].iloc[i-1]
        if subs['type'].iloc[i] == 'OUT':
            subs['vlineup'].iloc[i].remove(subs['checkname'].iloc[i])
        elif subs['type'].iloc[i] == 'IN':
            subs['vlineup'].iloc[i].append(subs['checkname'].iloc[i])
```

I feel as if I am close to getting the right output, but the output that I'm currently getting is just the last lineup filled in every cell for the vlineup and hlineup column.  Any direction would help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show an example of your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're trying to do, since I don't have the data to check.

But try this:

```
for i in range (1, len(subs)):
    if subs['team'][i] == home:      
        if subs['type'][i-1] == 'OUT':
            subs['hlineup'][i].remove(subs['checkname'][i-1])           
        elif subs['type'][i] == 'IN':
            subs['hlineup'][i].append(subs['checkname'][i-1])
    elif subs['team'] == visitor:
        if subs['type'][i] == 'OUT':
            subs['vlineup'][i].remove(subs['checkname'][i-1])
        elif subs['type'][i] == 'IN':
            subs['vlineup'][i].append(subs['checkname'][i-1])
```